# Migrating Oracle 10g Enterprise to AWS RDS oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, migration, rds

I have been assigned to move 10g database to AWS Oracle 12c.  Size of data is around 20 GB of actual data but 900 GB has been allocated. So we will need to decrease that. Any suggestions on how to migrate and reduce the size of the database?

Comment: Amazon should be able to help advise on the best way to migrate the data to their platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good summary of several options:
[Importing Data Into Oracle on Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html)

Also here is the [Oracle migration Whitepaper.](http://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/strategies-for-migrating-oracle-database-to-aws.pdf)

The solution depends on the size of your data and the accepted downtime.

Personally I used Data Dump in a project, it works well for the size of data you have. I'm not sure about the resizing.